# c# Is there a simple way to take a multi-split array and turn it into just one, sequential array?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

So basically, I have a string "one-two;three-four;five-six"

When I split ';' it becomes an array:

```
one-two  three-four  five-six
  [0]       [1]        [2]
```

Then foreach(string s in array), I split the '-', it becomes

```
one  two     three  four     five  six
[0]  [1]      [0]   [1]       [0]  [1]
```

I would like it so that it is an array like so:

```
one two three four five six
[0] [1]  [2]   [3]  [4] [5]
```

For reference, my code is pretty much the following at the moment. 
(Peharps I should create a list...?)

```
string pairsList="one-two;three-four;five-six";

string[] pairArray=pairsList.Split(';');

foreach(string s in pairArray)
{
    string[] splitPair=s.Split(',');
}
```

Comment: `string.Split` takes an array of characters to split by, so in your case, see if `string[] pairArray = pairsList.Split(';', '-');` won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly there:

```
string pairsList="one-two;three-four;five-six";
List<string> result = new List<string>();

string[] pairArray=pairsList.Split(';');

foreach(string s in pairArray)
{
    string[] splitPair=s.Split('-');
    foreach (var thing in splitPair)
    {
        result.add(thing);
    }
}

return result.ToArray();
```

Even better: split on all tokens at once:

```
string pairsList="one-two;three-four;five-six";

string[] pairArray=pairsList.Split(';', '-');

return pairArray;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply ask `string.Split` to split by the `-` as well.

[`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `params char[] separator` argument list so you can simply ask it to split by `-` as well:

```
string[] pairArray = pairsList.Split(';', '-' );
```